# read datable and store value in array

Tags: vb.net

```
Name | CategorieID | FullCategorie_ID
----  -------------  ----------------
 A        1             12  
 B        1             13
 C        5             14
 D        3             15
 E        6             16
```

I want to read data from `datatable` and store a complete row in array and then return it

Comment: What row you want to store? You could get all rows with `Dim allRows As DataRow() = table.Select()`

Comment: in a loop have to store each row till count is 0

Comment: I want to write a funtion which read the entire datable,put the value in string/array and then return it.

Comment: @user10285893 How do you want to store it in an Array? like `A112`, `B113`, `C514`, ecc?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot get the point to save a `DataTable` (that has rows and columns) inside an `Array` (that has only rows) but this is your question, not mine!

So, the code you are looking for is something like this:

```
Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable
Dim arrayString(dt.Rows.Count - 1) As String
For dr As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count
    For dc As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count
        arrayString(dr) = arrayString(dr) & "$" & dt.Rows(dr).Item(dc)
        'I added a special char ($) to easily split up data later
    Next
Next
```

If you want to split up in columns your data, just use `String.Split` like shown below:

```
Dim first_array_row () as String = arrayString.Split("$")
```

But I higly suggest you to review your code/idea, It's better for you to find another way, because this workaround is horrible.

Instead why not use a [List Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) and a [Dictionary Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

something like:

```
Dim values As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))()
```

Comment: `Dim arrayString(dt.Rows.Count()) As String` Why the extra element in this array?

Comment: what do you mean with extra element?

Comment: Arrays in vb.net start at index 0 and are declared array(upper bound). Perhaps you are confusing it with C# arrays which are array(number of elements). It should be dt.rows.Count - 1

Comment: `arrayString(dr) = arrayString(dr) & "$" & dt.Rows(dr).Item(dc)` This line will cause an index out of bounds error for the same reason.

Comment: Apparently you do not use Option Strict because the above line will not compile with it on. You really should use it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Mary, i edited my answer with `.count - 1`

Comment: No, I'm not using Option Strict

Comment: Option Strict will save you many hours of tracking down mysterious bug. Compile time error good. Runtime error bad.

Comment: The comment by @Tim Schmelter has the solution with one line of code. Works for me.

Comment: @Mary yes i know! I want to give the OP another variant of the same solution. Also if i prefer to work with DataTables and not weird array

Comment: One more tiny thing. .Count is a property and should not be followed by (). The parenthesis is for methods. Strictly enforced in C#. Casually added in the vb IDE or sometimes even skipped like with .ToString but get in the habit so when you need to write C# it will be easier.

Comment: @Mary when i learned vb.net, visual studio was automatically adding `()` to `.count`. Nice to hear that is useless